# Subtract two CHARINDEX values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, charindex

Update - let's look at the second field and I get results just fine...  I still get the error of the first..  I need to figure out the first..  I think what I need to is to remove the first..

This works..  Second length

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(AFIELD,
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1),
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)+1) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)) as [second_length]
FROM SOMETABLE with (nolock)
```

Third length which also works..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AFIELD,
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1),
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)+1)-CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)) as [THIRD_length]
FROM SOMETABLE with (nolock)
```

This is still not working..  Hmmm..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(AFIELD,
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD),
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)-CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)) as [FIRST_length]
FROM SOMETABLE with (nolock)
```

Old info..
This works fine..

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)[first]
,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), AFIELD)+1)[second]
FROM SOMETABLE
```

But when I try to subtract the two, the results are empty..

I have followed the information posted here and at - http://phelabaum.com/archive/tag/charindex/

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(AFIELD,
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),AFIELD)+1,
CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),AFIELD,CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),AFIELD)+1) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),AFIELD)) as [first_length]
FROM SOMETABLE
```

When I run this, I get: the message:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

The field is CHAR(10) or Line Feed delimited.

Comment: Seems to work just fine:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf84c/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf84c/1) if text you're testing indeed has 2 `CHAR(10)` in it with some text in between. If at least one is missing - you will get that error.

Note that `CHARINDEX` by itself will not return any errors if char is not found - it will simple return 0, this is why your first query runs.

Comment: looks like the SQL fiddle needs a bit of updating - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f8a85/1